# Sugar and milk, please!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> I am extra-large, that you know
>   Balancing temperatures, when it's low
>   Only one of my kind
>   All letters aligned
>   If you didn't find me yet,
>   I'm hidden in a statuette.

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> **40**

Because

> T-shirts come in *extra-large* → **XL** = 40 (roman numerals),
>  Balancing temperatures, when it's low → **-40C = -40F**, balancing temps,
>  Only one of my kind, All letters aligned → letters in **forty** are in alphabetical order, the only numerical word with this property,
>  And *40*→**Four-T** is hidden in a s**t**a**t**ue**tt**e.
>
>  The title, too is an allusion to **four tea**.  How do you take yours?

Thanks to @Techidiot and the other TSL regulars for the proper answers.

Comment: This fits well for most of it, but not for the temperature. Try again!

Comment: [statuette (hover on the link)](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/46994/19765 "the letters 't' 'e' and 'a' are all in statuette")

Comment: @Rubio XL for Forty